# Отправка Bitmap на сервер vk через POST-запрос

Tags: c#, vkontakte-api, post

В программе имеется Bitmap, который позже сохраняется в .jpg. Затем в формате multipart/form-data передается в POST-запросе на сервер вк.
Как избежать стадии сохранения Bitmap и посылать его напрямую из программы?

```
 Bitmap image;
 //Тут его сохраняю
 //Затем делаю запрос
 var httpClient = new HttpClient();
 var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
 FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\image.jpg");
 var streamContent = new StreamContent(fs);
 var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(streamContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result);
 imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");
 form.Add(imageContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\image.jpg"));
 var response = httpClient.PostAsync(uploadUrl, form).Result;
 //и т.д.
```

Comment: Попробуйте поработать с классом MemoryStream

Comment: @EgorRandomize спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил так:

```
var image = new Bitmap(); //мой битмап  
var ms = new MemoryStream()
imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] fileContents = ms.ToArray();  
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();                
var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(fileContents);
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("multipart/form-data");     
form.Add(imageContent, "file", "image.jpg");
//потом POST-запрос
```

Надо бы освободить ресурсы, но пишу так, чтобы было попонятнее.